# How to include a header file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, include-path

I am trying to implement #include "Base64.h"
The path to the file is "E:\Visual_Studio_2015\SR_libraries\arduino-base64-master\Base64.h"

I have added a reference Base64.h as an existing item under Header Files in Solution Explorer and clicking that reference opens the code file. I have added the directory where the file lives to the solution Property Page >> VC++ Directories >> Include Directories.

This doesn't work. In the code window, the #include statement is marked error (ragged red underscore.) Clicking calls up the build path where the file is not found. Said path indeed does not reflect my addition to Include Directories.

I would welcome any help on how to do this.

Comment: When you change the VC++ Directories setting then you have to use `#include <Base64.h>` instead.  Note the angle brackets instead of the double quotes.  Not a great idea, this should be reserved to compiler and operating system includes.  Favor the Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories setting instead.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't do it. I'm not able to post a picture, but I have examples with "file.h" and with <file2.h> and neither work. Also, in VS 2015, Project > Properties > C/C++ > General >    does not show an option for Additional Include Directories.

Comment: And I would appreciate illumination as to why adding reference to my header files in, respectively, Header Files and Resource Files of the Solution Explorer a) makes my code accessible to a click but b) does not make it available for compilation.  Thanks